# where is local hadoop folder in pyspark (mac)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, homebrew

I have installed pyspark in local mac using homebrew. I am able to see spark under /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/
but not able to see hadoop folder. If I run pyspark in terminal it is running spark shell.
Where can I see its path?

Comment: Why do you expect a local Hadoop folder? There's none.

Comment: So I a trying to connect S3 to pyspark and I have dependency jars, in which folder Do I need to keep them?

Comment: `jars` should be just fine.

Comment: will this be enough spark-submit --jars aws-java-sdk-1.11.901.jar,hadoop-aws-3.3.1.jar test.py ? I haven't downloaded any files ?

Comment: I am using hadoop 3.3.1 version

Answer (score 1):

> I a trying to connect S3 to pyspark and I have dependency jars

You do not need to know the location of Hadoop to do this.

You should use a command like `spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1 app.py` instead, which will pull all necessary dependencies rather than download all JARs (with their dependencies) locally.